# Hidden email body through MFMail Composer

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

i am sending a mail which having prefilled email body.  I want that sender can't see the email body but the receiver can see.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this using these views. If you access the user's mailbox, the user gets the final word on what gets sent out using her accounts. You can pre-load it, but the user gets to see *and change* the recipients, body, basically everything.

If you want to send some other kind of email, you will have to either contact a server and have it create and send the email for you or you will have to actually connect to a mail exchange server that *you* have send rights to and send the email from there using SMTP protocol yourself. You won't be able to send the email as the user, however, or using the user's accounts or authorization.

Comment: i want that user can't change anything on that view

Comment: @user509543 You can't have that. If you're sending mail as the user, she can see and edit everything.